# Best approach to handle login and authorizations in Vaadin Flow?

Tags: java, mysql, authentication, web, vaadin

I'm using Vaadin Flow to develop a web app with Java. I would like to know the best way to handle login and authorization. I've been giving this a thought and I'm not sure the best way to do this.

I have a login view and a main app view with a content holder for nested layouts.

How do I check that the user is logged in and what permissions does it have to see or not see some part of the app? I've read about BeforeEnterEvent and ReRouting but it's still not very clear.

- Do I have to use BeforeEnterEvent for each class I have? Do I have to create a class with user parameters like a boolean to check if it's logged in and a string for the kind of authorization it has? And where do I create or save this instance?
- Is there a simple way to do this? Like to start with an empty layout and to start that with the login screen, then the login screen decides to swap for the main app view? And how do I prevent the user to type the address of the main view in the bar and access parts it shouldn't access like: /app/adminsettings

I'm sure this is way simpler but I think I have my head overloaded by now, thanks anyone in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/securing-your-app-with-spring-security ?

Comment: I haven't @cfrick, seems that's all I need to, thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

As always, there are no silver bullets. The "best way" always depends on
the requirements and your options range from Basic Auth to some external
OIDC provider.

There are already some tutorials out there with the most prominent from
Vaadin itself about [Spring
Security](https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/securing-your-app-with-spring-security)
(which in a previous iteration had a flaw that compromised security,
which of course shows again, that security is no product but a process
and demands constant validation).

So I want to strategize here a bit more about the problems you are
facing and some things to consider:

- Be aware, that when you use a security library, that has or allows for
  an web path centric approach, that you should only use it for the
  root and to open up paths to resources etc.  The history API may only
  look like you are fetching URLs from a server or web sockets may be
  used under the hood and suddenly those rules no longer apply.
- If you are using the annotation based way to add routes, you end up
  with all the routes, that are there, for your UI per user.  So it's
  good to familiarize yourself with how to [register routes
  dynamically](https://vaadin.com/docs/flow/routing/tutorial-router-dynamic-routes.html).
  E.g. only add the routes the user is allowed on login; this usually
  also has implications for the UI (e.g. menu entries).
- There usually is some initial "declarative" security part (can the
  user even enter this view; this usually means some simple role check).
  A good place to check for this is a `BeforeEnterListener` added to **the
  UI**; it will be called **before any navigation to any view**.  See
  [navigation
  livecyle](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/routing/tutorial-routing-lifecycle.html)
- The next entry point(s) to guard are the `BeforeEnterEvent` you can
  listen on in the view itself and/or maybe it implements
  `HasUrlParameter`.  If you take params from the "request" or the path,
  the usually mean further checks (e.g. is the acting user allowed to
  edit the blog entry with the id 42).  See [routing and URL
  parameters](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/routing/tutorial-router-url-parameters.html)
  and also [navigation
  livecyle](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/routing/tutorial-routing-lifecycle.html).
- Deeper into the application you end up with something more imperative,
  that libraries often make appear declarative, because they generate
  some code for you from some annotation (e.g. some AOP that generates
  the code around your `@SecurityCheck('${u.owner}==${currentUser}')
  void save(User u)` method, that checks for the role and whether the
  `User u` belongs to the acting user).

  Be very certain, that your IoC system/library/... sees those
  annotation and generates the code accordingly.  Only `@Route` e.g.
  will get the full DI treatment with Vaadin+Spring - for the rest it's
  your job that the DI-framework can do it's job (a NPE from a missed
  `@Autowired` is spotted very quickly, but a security check not being
  called, is not).  The obvious way around this, is to be imperative and
  write the code yourself instead of relying on it to be there.
- If you have an anonymous system and then some login, make sure to send
  users over to a fresh session (and therefor UI); not only does it
  prevent a session fixation attack, but it also allows you put all your
  route-setup and UI derivations according to security in one place at
  the beginning of the UI creation.  If you have state you want to carry
  over, make it part of the URL, that your successful login process
  sends them back to or park in the browsers local storage.